# Is a Server-side Javascript website possible without using client-side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Server-Side JavaScript and Node.js. Will a website work if the user has JavaScript disabled or their browser does not support JavaScript?

I understand that it's *Server-side JavaScript*, but, what I'm asking is; Do I need to use client-side JavaScript if I want a website built with Server-Side JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NodeJs will run regardless of browser settings. It runs on the server without any knowledge of the user's settings.
You can build a web server in Node and make http requests to it from your browser even if the browser doesn't support javascript.

Comment: Oh that is awesome news. Thanks tou @TGH

Comment: I have been reading about SSJS all night, and I see that there are many frameworks for creating SSJS websites. However I am confused about one thing. Is Node.js a Server-Side JavaScript framework? Can I serve *.ssjs files with Node.js?

Comment: Node is a framework for creating web servers. It can essentially serve whatever content you want it to. Node is a bit low level, so  you might find it helpful to use another framework called Express on top of Node to get some typical web server features "for free" There are other frameworks to use in combination with Node and Express is one of them